# jquery animate help needed

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I am using animate in jQuery. I am getting problem  to execute animate. It executes after test function I want to run this before test function

```
 $('.next').live('click',function() {
                    $('.ac_bgimage').animate({
                        left:"-100em"    
                    }, 15000 );
                    test();
                });
```

but now when i click on next class my test function  execute first , i want to execute later after execution of animate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to put it into callback function

```
 $('.next').live('click',function() {
        $('.ac_bgimage').animate({
           left:"-100em"    
        }, 15000 , function(){
           test();
        });                
  });
```

Comment: You dont need to wrap test function into another anonymouse IMHO

Comment: @JanPfeifer: yes I need, when OP wants to call test() after animation is done

Comment: @HituBansal: no it doesn't. Let my try

Comment: @genesis φ: shouldnt be  '... }, 15000 , test ); });' enough?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
   $('.next').live('click',function() {
                $('.ac_bgimage').animate({
                    left:"-100em"    
                }, 15000, function() { test();} );
            });
```